# how to change other siblings value to in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Playing aroud with vue with a todo list.

At this stage, I am able to  show the list within and with an edit button, the text will be an input so I can edit the todo items.  But for example if I have 10 items, and I clicked edit for item 2 and item 4 and item 5, then all these 3 items will change into input.

What I am thinking is if I click on item 4, item 2 will change back to text, so only one item will show input if edit clicked.

I have my template code as below

```
<td class="col-8">
  <!-- if editable is false, show the checkbox and todo item -->
  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" v-if="!editable">
      {{ todo.item }}
  </div>

  <!-- if editable is true, turn item into an input so user can enter new value -->
  <div v-else>
    <input ref="editItem" type="text" class="form-control" :value="todo.item" @input="onInput">
  </div>
</td>
<td class="col-2">
  <button
    class="btn btn-sm"
    :class="editable ? 'btn-outline-success' : 'btn-outline-info'"
    @click.prevent="editable ? onSave() : onEdit()">{{ editable ? 'save' : 'edit' }}
  </button>
</td>
```

As I open up the vue inspect in chrome, I can see all items have their different data value.
How can I change others siblings' value?

[image]

Thanks in advance for any sugguestins and advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend you to change the value of another sibling, since you cannot be sure of the side-effects it can cause, obviously when you look at a todo list, it would feel like there are no side-effects but in general practice, a node should change elements that are below it in the parentage, neither above nor the siblings.

If you want to change elements above, its always drive via events. You let the parent know that something needs to be changed rather than changing it yourself.

This is what you can do here:

1. Rather using `editable` as a data property, use it as a prop to the TodoListItem component.

```
    props: {
      editable: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
    }
```

2. When the Save/Edit button is clicked in the child component, rather than changing the value there itself, use events like so.

```
/** You should keep a deepCopy of the props if you are changing the state
 of that object and then send the updated local data prop to the parent 
 as well for updation rather than changing the prop object.
 NEVER CHANGE THE PROP OBJECT DIRECTLY. -> this.todoItem = 
 this.deepCopy(this.todo); 
 Do this in before mount hook of the child component.
**/
this.$emit('todo-item-action', action, todoItem);
```

3. Once this event is emitted, in the parent `TodoList` component, catch this event and change the state of the items like so:

```
      <todo-list-item
        v-for="todo in todos"
        :key="todo['id']"
        :todo="todo"
        :editable="todo['editable']"
        @todo-item-action="handleItemAction"
      >
```

or if you don't want to mutate the todo object. here you can make sure editableItem is `null` if none is selected or only the active item ID is referred so that the prop will change and automatically other list item will become un-editable.

```
      <todo-list-item
        v-for="todo in todos"
        :key="todo['id']"
        :todo="todo"
        :editable="editableItem === todo['id']"
        @todo-item-action="handleItemAction"
      >
```

The more you drive a component via events and props, the more re-usable it becomes. Always have an orchestrator component which manipulates these `stateless` components by handling events propogated by them and sending state via props.

This is the approach I have always followed and it always allow me to refactor cleanly and quickly.

Regards.

Comment: so basically saying is letting the parent to take the control, the child list when clicked on `edit` will `$emit` to the parent, and using the `id` of the item comparing with the list while rendering in parent which will then pass the `editable` props to child

Comment: I agree, by default the path is props and emits as your communication mechanism for pushing data up and down across components. If that gets to be too unwieldy, i.e. having to prop drill through multiple child components or relay emits through multiple parents, that is where you commonly see recommendations to move to a state management module like Vuex.

Comment: @MikeWright totally understand if there are layers to go,  just haven't really dig into vuex yet and pretty much want to make this todo list to use vuex soon as learning.  But I would assume, even though at this moment I am not pass few layers up and down, it would still be better to use vuex so passing through layers will not be needed?

Comment: by keeping deepCopy of the props instead of changing it directly would mean something like if I edited my item value `onSave` method, which calls an api to do the edit but after the request is a success, I should not do something like `this.todo.item = newItemValue` but instead `$emit` to the parent where all my item list data is?

Comment: @Dora Yes, mutating a prop value always leads to unexpected behaviour. The value in the parent component changes by reference without the parent even knowing, so lets say you added an intermediate event in the parent, who does not know that the value it was expecting has been changed, it would caused undesirable outcomes. More than anything, this approach of explicitly setting value in the parent is more readable, else if you change the value of the prop, the parent component's value would change but a new dev will never understand what is happening and why.